# Declaring const variable in function or file?

Tags: c, constants, global, declaration

So I'm integrating some old drivers and implementation for LCDs. 
They have images declared as static const uint8_t image[]. Sometimes declared within the file globally, sometimes declared within the function that draws that.

What are the advantages to each declaration? Why are some one way or the other?

It seems to me if you declare it within the function and that function isn't used, might save some space? And if declared external to the function, that amount of memory is always used? Maybe not.

This is in C.

Right, I get that. I guess my follow up question should have been:
each image is only used once and has a corresponding function. For example:

```
const uint8_t image1[] = {};
void draw_image1() {
    //sends imag1 to SPI
}

void draw_image2() { 
    const uint8_t image2[] = {
        //image two data
    }
    //sends image2 to SPI lines
}
```

Do these take up memory differently once compiled? Is one better for different implementations. If we don't use these functions, does one implementation save memory or anything?

Comment: Please tag this question with the appropriate language tag (C?) since it is unlikely that there is a language-agnostic answer to this question.

Comment: Done. Sorry about that.

Comment: Can you edit to include some source examples? Sometimes programmers do dumb things, sometimes they're doing it for technical reasons. It really depends. Some things, like drivers, have specific constraints and you're forced to do ugly things.

Comment: An `static` object inside a function does not pollute the global name space.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica

Each of these are only used in one function. How are they handled in memory while running differently?

Comment: @somanyquestions The `static` object in a function allows for a same named `static` object in another function.  An object in a function shadows a global function.  True that `static const uint8_t image[]` name at file scope is not seen outside the file.

Comment: Right, I get that. I guess my follow up question should have been:
each image is only used once and has a coorisponding function. For example:

const uint8_t image1[] = {};
void draw_image1() { //sends imag1 to SPI}

void draw_image2() { 
const uint8_t image2[] = {//image two data}
//sends image2 to SPI lines
}

Do these take up memory differently once compiled? Is one better for different implementations. If we don't use these functions, does one implementation save memory or anything?

Comment: I don't have time for an elaborated answer, just my €0.02: `image1` will be a static variable initialized at compile- and/or load-time, and its name is visible globally. `image2` will be initialized at run-time on the stack, and its name is only visible inside `draw_image2()`.

Comment: @thebusybee -> so if global where is image 1 stored? And I guess we don't need as big of a stack if we use the image 1 method.

Comment: Beware about the stack: a good compiler would not use stack for a static const variable. In an  embedded system, "static const" is a big improvement. You said in the question "static ...", but in the code you posted I don't see it.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica That's right, it's in the code, but not in the prose. Any local variable can be made `static`, but it will be the only instance of it. Any value that never changes during run-time can be an immediate value or a `const static` value.

Comment: See http://c-faq.com/decl/index.html, specifically, http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~freedman/241/241notes/241var2.htm. Especially when working with images, the author may have been conscious of the capacity of each storage class.